# 18.04 Gnome Desktop No permanent workspace number shown on desktop

Tags: 18.04, gnome, 20.04, workspaces

I have not been able to get the current workspace number permanently on the desktop.  If I press the window key, of course I can get it, but find this annoying.  I have 4 fixed workspaces, set by gnome-tweaks.  I note that Fedora 28 Gnome has the workspace number on the status line ( showing 2/4 to indicate workspace 2 of 4).

Comment: correction: "I have 4 fixed windows" should be 4 fixed workspaces.

Comment: Rather than commenting on your own question, you can click the edit button below it and revise it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the following gnome extension:

[**workspace-indicator**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/)

[image]

**Or install from Ubuntu package** with the default Gnome Shell extensions - it's probably more reliable.

You can install it using:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

After installing that package, restart Gnome Shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing <kbd>r</kbd>, then press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
And finally enable the "Workspace Indicator" extension using **Gnome Tweaks**.

Comment: Not sure what extension fedora uses, where according to the OP it apparently shows "1/4", etc. on the status line (aka top bar?)

Comment: I'd recommend using the Ubuntu package with the default Gnome Shell extensions - it's probably more reliable. You can install it using: "sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions". After installing that package, restart Gnome Shell using Alt + F2 and typing "r" (without the quotes), then press the Enter key. And finally enable the "Workspace Indicator" extension using Gnome Tweaks.

Comment: Logix and abu_bua: Your procedure worked (others I tried did not). Thanks.